# Vuetify : v-navigation-drawer

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app class="blue darken-5">
    <v-list>
        <v-list-tile v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" router :to="link.route">
            <v-list-tile-action>
                <v-icon class="white--text">{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-action>

            <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title class="white--text"> {{ link.text }} </v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

I was expecting to get sth like this

[image]

But I kept getting this

[image]

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you have a typo in your code! all of the 'tile's should be 'item' instead.

like `v-list-item` instead of `v-list-tile`.

check the demo below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: true,
      links: [{
          text: 'home',
          icon: 'mdi-home'
        },
        {
          text: 'watch',
          icon: 'mdi-eye'
        },
        {
          text: 'user',
          icon: 'mdi-account'
        },
      ]
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app class="blue darken-5">
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item v-for="link in links" :key="link.text">
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon class="white--text">{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title class="white--text"> {{ link.text }} </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Was it deprecated? I followed a tutorial from here : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnxplXitv8w&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g0MQZfHwKcuB0Yswgb3gA5&index=10&ab_channel=TheNetNinja

Comment: @code8888 it's been a long time that I'm using vuetify and as far as I remember it has always been `item`, but I checked out the tutorial and its from 2018, so it might be deprecated ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I suggest you to check vuetify's doc since it has a really good one and it's full of ready to use examples